# I have problems with the command Ionic 3 and Firebase and angularfire2

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have problems with the command

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

In Ionic 3 And Firebase use plugin angularfire2

When I execute it, it starts but stays locked indefinitely and never ends.

sample run result command
Running app-scripts build: --prod --platform android --target cordova

```
[13:30:05] build prod started ...
[13:30:05] clean started ...
[13:30:05] clean finished in 2 ms
[13:30:05] copy started ...
[13:30:05] deeplinks started ...
[13:30:06] deeplinks finished in 122 ms
[13:30:06] ngc started ...
[13:30:16] ngc finished in 10.44 s
[13:30:16] preprocess started ...
[13:30:16] preprocess finished in 1 ms
[13:30:16] webpack started ...
[13:30:16] copy finished in 10.92 s
```

I have verified that it crashes when I use the Firebase plugin angularfire2 with the modules AngularFireDatabaseModule, AngularFireDatabase.
I have tried different versions of angularfire2

I tried this

```
npm install angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.4
npm install firebase@^4.5.0
```

It is also

```
npm install angularfire2 firebase promise-polyfill --save
npm install --save @ firebase / app-types
```

I have a MacPro this is the configuration

```
node -v
v8.11.0

npm -v
5.8.0

ng -v
Angular CLI: 6.0.1
Node: 8.11.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.2.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic

Package Version
-------------------------------------------------- ---------
@ angular-devkit / architect 0.6.1
@ angular-devkit / build-optimizer 0.0.35
@ angular-devkit / core 0.6.1
@ angular-devkit / schematics 0.6.1
@ angular / cli 6.0.1
@ schematics / angular 0.6.1
@ schematics / update 0.6.1
rxjs 5.5.8
typescript 2.6.2
webpack 3.8.1


cordova -v
8.0.0


ionic -v
3.20.0


ionic info

cli packages: (/ usr / local / lib / node_modules)

    @ ionic / cli-utils: 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI): 3.20.0

global packages:

    Cordova (Cordova CLI): 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ ionic / app-scripts: 3.1.9
    Cordova Platforms: android 6.3.0
    Ionic Framework: ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools: 26.1.1
    ios-deploy: 1.9.2
    Node: v8.11.0
    npm: 5.8.0
    OS: macOS High Sierra
    Xcode: Xcode 9.3.1 Build version 9E501

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME: / Users / user / Developed / Android / sdk

Misc:

    backend: pro
```

Someone has some idea that can be.

If I use the command
ionic cordova build android --release
It works fine but causes a delay in opening the application after while screen of about 8 seconds.